# testng suite results are not providing the right count

Tags: testng

As per the discussions provided in the forum, the way to change the count of failures,skip tests based on the retry count is not working as expected.The listeners have been included in the testng.xml in suite so not sure why the count is not getting modified. testng version: 6.14.3

```
/*Test class*/

    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
    import org.testng.ITestNGListener;
    import org.testng.ISuiteListener;
    import org.testng.ISuite;


    public class TestclassTest{
        Testclass t = new Testclass();

          @Test
          public void compareDataClassValues() {
              Assert.assertEquals(t.compareDataClassValues(1, 0), true);
              Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
              Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
          }
    }
```

/*Listener*/

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import org.testng.IResultMap;
    import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
    import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
    import org.testng.ITestContext;
    import org.testng.ITestListener;
    import org.testng.ITestNGListener;
    import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;

    public class Listener implements ITestListener  {
        //  RetryFailure oretry= new RetryFailure();

        public Listener() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
            System.out.println("test start");


        }

        public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test success");

        }

        public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test failure");

        }

        public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test skip");
            //      result.
        }

        public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage");

        }

        public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test onStart");
            System.out.println(context.getOutputDirectory());
            System.out.println(context.getHost());
            ITestNGMethod[] itest= context.getAllTestMethods();
            for (ITestNGMethod i : itest) {
                System.out.println(i.getMethodName());
                System.out.println(i.getCurrentInvocationCount());
            }

            System.out.println(context.getStartDate());
        }

        public void onFinish(ITestContext context,ITestResult result) {
            System.out.println("test onFinish with failure");
        }

        public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
            ITestResult result;
            //      result.getTestContext().get
            Integer number =0;
            System.out.println("test onFinish");

            System.out.println(context.getSuite().getResults());
            IResultMap mpassed = context.getPassedTests();
            IResultMap mfailed1 = context.getFailedTests();
            IResultMap mskipped1 = context.getSkippedTests();
            Set<ITestResult> mpassedResults = mpassed.getAllResults();
            Set<ITestResult> mfailed1Results = mfailed1.getAllResults();
            Set<ITestResult> mskippedResults = mskipped1.getAllResults();

            Map<String, ISuiteResult>  suiteres = (context.getSuite().getResults());
            System.out.println(suiteres.keySet().toString());
            System.out.println(suiteres.values().toString());


            mfailed1Results.removeAll(mskippedResults);
            for (ITestResult iTestResult2 : mfailed1Results) {
                System.out.println(iTestResult2.getMethod().getMethodName() + "  Failed Method name");
                if (mpassedResults.size() > 0){
                    if (mpassedResults.contains(iTestResult2.getMethod())) {
                        mfailed1Results.remove(iTestResult2);
                        mskippedResults.remove(iTestResult2);
                    }
                }
                else if (mskippedResults.size() > 0){
                    System.out.println(mskipped1.getAllMethods().toString() + "  skipped Method  name");
                    mskippedResults.remove(iTestResult2);
                    System.out.println(mskippedResults.toString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

/*Retry analyser*/

```
    public class RetryFailure implements IRetryAnalyzer {

        int retryCount = 0;
        public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
            System.out.println("retry method");
            final int maxRetryCount = 2;
            if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
                System.out.println("retry " + retryCount);
                retryCount = retryCount + 1; 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

/*Retry Listener*/
    public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {

        public RetryListener() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            IRetryAnalyzer retry = annotation.getRetryAnalyzer();
            if(retry == null){
                annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryFailure.class);
            }

        }

        public void transform(IConfigurationAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
                Method testMethod) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void transform(IDataProviderAnnotation annotation, Method method) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void transform(IFactoryAnnotation annotation, Method method) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```